# Logging error when syncdb

Tags: django

Can you please help to solve below bug.

```
ValueError: Unable to configure filter 'special': Cannot resolve 'project.logging.SpecialFilter': No module named project
```

Thanks

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    commands = get_commands()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 107, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 50, in _setup
    self._configure_logging()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 80, in _configure_logging
    logging_config_func(self.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 777, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 562, in configure
    'filter %r: %s' % (name, e))
ValueError: Unable to configure filter 'special': Cannot resolve 'project.logging.SpecialFilter': No module named project
ubuntu@ip-172-31-10-91:/data/apache/serve/web-app/datagatheringwebapp$ python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    commands = get_commands()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 107, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 50, in _setup
    self._configure_logging()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 80, in _configure_logging
    logging_config_func(self.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 777, in dictConfig
    dictConfigClass(config).configure()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/config.py", line 562, in configure
    'filter %r: %s' % (name, e))
ValueError: Unable to configure filter 'special': Cannot resolve 'project.logging.SpecialFilter': No module named project
```

Comment: please show some code so the SO community can help you

Comment: its just manage.py syncdb command. and this work in my local server.but stopped in live,
Thanks

Comment: So it want's to import something from project. But it can't find it

Comment: and this could be cause the folder its in is named differently, or there is no __init__.py in this folder or it is a file which was not coppied or you wsgi script has a diffrent documentroot dir.

Comment: Search for __'__init__.py'__ in project directory. If missing this is the problem

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because 'project.logging.SpecialFilter' doesn't exist and you have to create this class/method in your django project.

Create module 'mylogging.py' in / directory, where settings.py and wsgi.py and url.py is present. 
A sample SpecialFilter implementation:-

```
    import logging
from random import choice

class SpecialFilter(logging.Filter):
    # """
    # This is a filter which injects contextual information into the log.
    # 
    # Rather than use actual contextual information, we just use random
    # data in this demo.
    # """

    USERS = ['jim', 'fred', 'sheila']
    IPS = ['123.231.231.123', '127.0.0.1', '192.168.0.1']

    def filter(self, record):

        record.ip = choice(SpecialFilter.IPS)
        record.user = choice(SpecialFilter.USERS)
        return True
```

Also fix your setting.py to properly point to the new SpecialFilter module location.

```
    'filters': {
    'special': {
        '()': '<your_project_name>.mylogging.SpecialFilter',
        # '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
        # 'foo': 'bar',
    },
```